# Asymptote only generates full-page PDF output

Tags: asymptote

I have a LaTeX document in which I include several asymptote images, and I can't seem to get the generated PDF to be cropped. Asymptote always generates a full-page PDF...

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline,attach]{asymptote}
\usepackage[dvips]{attachfile2}

\begin{asydef}
settings.embed=true;
settings.render=1;
import graph;
import graph3;
import contour3;

material reds =  material(diffusepen=0.7red,ambientpen=red,emissivepen=0.3*red,specularpen=0.95white,shininess=0.95);
material blues = material(diffusepen=0.7blue,ambientpen=blue,emissivepen=0.3*blue,specularpen=0.95white,shininess=0.95);

int numberlines=8;

defaultrender.merge=true;
defaultrender.tessellate=true;
defaultrender.compression=Low;
\end{asydef}

\begin{document}
First sentence
\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
    picture p1,p2;
    size(p1,100);
    size(p2,100);

    real f(real x, real y, real z) {return y^2+x-2;}
    real c(real x, real y, real z) {return 2*x+2*z -2;}

    draw(p1,surface(contour3(f,(-3,-3,-3),(3,3,3),numberlines)),reds);
    draw(p1,surface(contour3(c,(-3,-3,-3),(3,3,3),numberlines)),blues);
    draw(p2,surface(contour3(f,(-3,-3,-3),(3,3,3),numberlines)),reds);
    draw(p2,surface(contour3(c,(-3,-3,-3),(3,3,3),numberlines)),blues);

    currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(9,10,4),up=Z,target=O,zoom=1);
    add(p2.fit(currentprojection),(0,0),W);
    currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(0,7,7),up=Z,target=O,zoom=1);
    add(p1.fit(currentprojection),(0,0),30E);
\end{asy}
\end{center}
Second sentence

\end{document}
```

In the output pdf, "First sentence" and "Second sentence" show up in separate pages, because asymptote creates a full-page PDF with a small image at the upper-left part of the page.

How can I get the image to be generated in a format that can be properly included in the LaTeX document?

Comment: Potentially relevant data: 1. Contents of your `~/.asy/config.asy`? 2. Does your Asymptote executable have support for OpenGL? 3. Does passing `-glOptions=-indirect` to the `asy` command help? 4. Does omitting `settings.render=1;` help?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the latest version of say where some figures aren't properly cropped. It has been reported.

Comment: This is a bug (although supposedly not in Asymptote itself). Based on [this discussion on the Asymptote forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/98f943a2/), adding the line `settings.tex = "latex";` might be a workaround, although that's unlikely to work with the `inline` option when loading the package.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. An easy fix is to reinstall asymptote and get the most recent version. As of the time of writing this, the asymptote.sty file should be at version 1.32 and the other files should have also been updated.

See [Asymptote images take up entire page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339874/asymptote-images-take-up-entire-page)