# Asymptote images take up entire page?

Tags: asymptote

I got a new computer and recently installed Asymptote on it. I use it with Texmaker. The issue I'm having is that whenever I produce an image with Asymptote, it takes up the entire page rather than being cropped to take up the space of the image. How do I resolve this issue?

EDIT: I found that this happens when the image has any labels, but the image gets resized to normal when no parts of the diagram have labels.

For example,

```
Sentence 2
\begin{asy}
unitsize(0.4 cm);
draw(circle((0,0), 2));
draw(circle((0,0), 4));
draw(circle((0,0), 6));
dot("$O$", (0,0));
\end{asy}
sentence 2
```

creates a full page-sized image in the PDF (the circles are the right size, but the rest of the image is filled with white space) that results in sentence 1 and sentence 2 being on different pages and

```
sentence 1
\begin{asy}
unitsize(0.4 cm);
draw(circle((0,0), 2));
draw(circle((0,0), 4));
draw(circle((0,0), 6));
dot((0,0));
\end{asy}
sentence 2
```

creates the image I want so that everything is on a single page, just missing the label.

The full .asy file is

```
if(!settings.multipleView) settings.batchView=false;
settings.tex="pdflatex";
defaultfilename="fileNameHere";
if(settings.render < 0) settings.render=4;
settings.outformat="";
settings.inlineimage=true;
settings.embed=true;
settings.toolbar=false;
viewportmargin=(2,2);

unitsize(0.4 cm);
draw(circle((0,0), 2));
draw(circle((0,0), 4));
draw(circle((0,0), 6));
dot("$O$", (0,0));
```

Comment: An [example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) might be useful.

Comment: The document, when run with pdflatex --shell-escape test, then asy test-1, and then pdflatex --shell-escape test, does not create a full page-sized image for me.

Comment: Make sure you update to the latest version of asymptote. The asymptote.sty file should be at version 1.32 and other files have also been updated.

Comment: I am using version 2.38, downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/?source=typ_redirect

I reinstalled asymptote, does not do anything

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is with GhostScript rather than asymptote?

Comment: Providing a complete example would be helpful, as suggested above.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct version of the `.sty` file etc.

Comment: Please precise also miktex/texlive version. 2016 texlive version and previous asymptote version have problem...

Comment: Please give us a complete `.tex` document and provide the information requested. Add `\listfiles` to get information about the versions of TeX files you are using. We don't know how many versions of Asymptote you have installed, which are being used, what distribution you're using, what code you are compiling ...

Comment: Probably you just need to update your TeX distribution. Certainly for TeX Live. Probably for MikTeX, assuming it has been updated by now.

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9, the latest version.

Comment: I have updated all packages for MikTex. I think the problem is in Asymptote because opening the .asy file creates a full-sized pdf image rather than the cropped image I want. It seems that this problem has been discussed in https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues/24 but I don't understand it and how to solve it.

Comment: Please read again the comment of cfr about `\listfiles` and gives us the messages...

Comment: Nvm. I have fixed the issue.

Comment: @Anonymous Was https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339996/24521 your fix? Better mention it in this question, or mark duplicate maybe